# How do you get color to show in iTerm2?

Tags: terminal, color-scheme, iterm2

### How do you get color to show in iTerm2 or in the terminal?

I managed to get my Vim editor to show color. Here's what I have in my .vimrc file.

> set term=xterm-256color
>
> color scheme evening
>
> syntax enable

From my research, I think there might be something missing from the terminfo file but I have no idea what to do with that. I am using Mac OS X 10.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use VIM and iTerm 2 on OS X 10.9.1. In my .vimrc, I have the following (note that I'm using the molokai colorscheme, you would switch that with 'evening'):

```
let &t_Co=256
colorscheme molokai
syntax on
```

Those settings worked best for me. Those settings also resolved some issues I was having with colors while using VIM in a tmux session.

Also, in iTerm's preferences, under Profile > *Whatever Profile You're Using* > Terminal, make sure "Report Terminal Type" is set to:

```
screen-256color
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`colorscheme` is supposed to be written as a single word.  I don't think setting `term` is necessary from within `.vimrc`.